# How do notifcation editing apps such as Clean Master work on Android?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I am looking to make an like this myself, but I can't seem to figure out how I can edit notifications from other applications. I know how to retrieve and read notifications from other applications, through the NotificationManager, but I don't know how to edit them through the notification manager.

Comment: Have look [Update Notification](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/managing.html)

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work I was wondering if this was because you can't change notifications that are not from your app?